# BroadcastReceiver or Messenger via Handler

Tags: android, android-service, android-sdk-2.1

I have an `IntentService` which need to pass a message to an `Activity`.
I know two ways of doing so.

1. use `sendBroadcast()` at the `Service` side while registering a `broadcastReciever` at the `Activity` side which will receiver the message.
2. passing a `Messenger` to the Service `side`, which will point to a `Handler` at the `Activity` side, which will be ready to receive that message from the service.

Which one is good for which purpose? Or both of them do the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your `IntentService` does not know whether the activity will exist (e.g., might have been destroyed), or if there are multiple activities that might be in the foreground and would want to know about what's going on, I'd use `sendOrderedBroadcast()`. You can arrange to then also have a "backstop" `BroadcastReceiver` that could raise a Notification, if desired, as I outline in [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) and demonstrate in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Broadcast/Ordered).

Either of your techniques can work, though.

Comment: So basically you say in case I dont care whether my Activity is "alive" or not both techniques servs the same purpose equally ?

Comment: @rayman: You'll get a `RemoteObjectException` with the `Messenger` if the `Activity` is gone when you try sending the message, but since it's a checked exception, you need to handle that anyway. If there is exactly one component that needs to find out about the event, and you don't need to raise a `Notification` if that component is not around, a `Messenger` is the lightest-weight solution.