# Which is the best way to communicate between service and activity?

Tags: android

Now Activity can connect to services using one of three ways:

- [BroadcastReceivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
- [Messengers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html)
- AIDL

I think that BroadcastReceivers is the easiest way to communicate but I'm wondering why and when to use other ways? or in other words in which cases messengers or AIDL will be the best practice to use than broadcastreceivers?

Comment: You should start from considering whether your service is running in the same process of your activity or it is running on a different process then your activity.

Comment: yeah I have used binding before and in my latest project, I used broadcasts and broadcasts are much easier to work with

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `BroadcastReceiver` when you want the communication between `Service` and `Activity` in your application.

`Messenger`'s and `AIDL`'s are mainly used when your application needs to communicate to other processes([IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)). In this case your interface should have a `Service` which defines a `Handler` that responds to different types of `Message` objects.

Now the difference between `Messenger` and `AIDL` is pretty simple. When you use `Messenger`, it queues all requests into a single thread. So your `Service` doesn't have to be thread safe. If, you want your `Service` to handle multiple requests simultaneously, then you can use `AIDL` directly. In this case, your `Service` must be capable of multi-threading and be built thread-safe. In fact `Messenger` is implemented on the top of `AIDL`.

For better understanding look at [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

You should also check the answer from [BroadcastReceiver or Messenger via Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372676/broadcastreceiver-or-messenger-via-handler)

Answer (score 13):

I mostly tend to use `LocalBroadcasts`. They essentially are like real broadcasts, but only visible to your application. First you have to create a `BroadcastReceiver` like you would with a normal broadcast:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(Intent.SOME_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Do your work
        }
    }
};
```

You can then register and unregister the `BroadcastReceiver` like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.SOME_ACTION);

    LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity());
    manager.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity());
    manager.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

And finally you can send a broadcast from your `Service` or anywhere else in your application like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.SOME_ACTION);

LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity());
manager.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Agreed. This, or third-party message buses (Square's Otto, greenrobot's EventBus), are the current best practices.

Comment: `Messengers` are not commonly used, that is also the reason why there is so little documentation on the subject. They are mostly used for communicating across different processes.

Comment: you cannot use LocalBroadcastManager across different processes (e.g. when communicating between an activity and a service running on a different process)

Answer (score 3):

**Xaver Kapeller**'s answer is indeed a good one. However, it has a (major) drawback: *broadcasts can be missed.*

When the user navigates away from the `Activity` (for example by showing the recent apps), you unregister your `BroadcastReceiver`s. If the broadcast is sent at that moment, your `Activity` does not receive it. When navigating back to your `Activity`, it might be in an invalid state.

---

Using a `ResultReceiver`, you still receive the result in this case. Furthermore, a `ResultReceiver` is `parcelable`, so you can save and restore it in the lifecycle events.
It causes some overhead though, which is why I've created [this experimental library](https://github.com/nhaarman/ergo) to ease it up a little. For now it only uses `IntentService`s, but it should be easy enough to extend.

Comment: Yeah it's true that broadcasts can be missed, but normally if your app absolutely depends on receiving the broadcast than you are doing something wrong. Local broadcasts should never be used to actually transfer data or anything like that. A use case for local broadcasts would for example be that you notify a `Fragment` that a task has finished or data has changed and needs to be reloaded, in other words things that are irrelevant to the state of the app itself, they just give extra - but essentially unnecessary - info.

Answer (score 2):

If your `service is used only by the local application` and does not need to work across processes, then you can implement your own `Binder class` that provides your client direct access to `public methods in the service`.

***Note: This works only if the client and service are in the same application and process`, which is most common.***

**Extending the Binder class** http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder